# access the system caret blink rate in java

Tags: java, swing, textbox, caret

I am implementing a simple embedded text editor in java. For the convenience of my users I would like to use the caret blink rate they have set as a system property in their operating system.

I am not using a swing or awt text box, but rather building one from scratch.

What is the simplest way to get at this system property?

Comment: I don't think that is an operating system thing, that is more of a your-job type of thing. For me, every application has a different blink rate, some blink once, then blink a bunch, others just constantly blink.

Comment: There is indeed a configurable blink rate on most OSes

Comment: In your question, you are asking how to access the global property for caret blink rate. As far as I know, such a property does not exist. Drawing UIs and rendering stuff is not the operating systems deal, but rather the library you are using. In this case, you are making your own so that setting is up to you!

Comment: I edited my previous comment while the previous comment was being typed. However, for the curious, the setting in question is under keyboard properties in windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method for configuring the cursor blink rate is highly system dependent, and there is no simple (cross-platform) way to access the rate in Java.

For example:

- On Linux - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55423/how-to-change-cursor-shape-color-and-blinkrate-of-linux-console
- On Windows - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971316.aspx#atg_avoidflashing_adjusting_the_cursor_blink_rate_programmatically

(These are not direct solutions ... but they illustrate the problem that you would have.)

---

I would put this application feature into the "too hard" basket, especially since the benefit to most users is (IMO) marginal.